# How to avoid newlines being added by HAML ruby block evaluation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm using the `content_for` helper to e.g. set a page title in my rails 3 app. One snippet of erb I'm still using in some places is

```
<title><%= yield(:title) -></title>
```

or written in HAML would be

```
%title= yield(:title)
```

Now I have a HAML template setting this title:

```
- content_for :title do
  My awesome title
- content_for :something_else do
```

which results in

```
<title>My awesome title
</title>
```

How can I avoid the newline before `</title>`? It's definitely set in `:title` – adding `+"X"` will put the `X` behind the newline.

I already tried

```
-< content_for :title do
-> content_for :title do
```

but either one leads to an error. Whitespace removal seems to be not working with ruby evaluation.

Comment: Why not just do:  `%title= content_for?(:title) ? "#{yield(:title)}" : "Default Title"`

Comment: It's not about a default title - I also have that. The problem is that even here, `yield(:title)` contains the trailing newline.

Comment: Interesting...  Two apps I have running Rails 3.2 both use the snippet I posted above and it works as you intend.

Comment: Hm. For me it doesn't. How do you set `content_for :title` then?

Comment: Example, line 1 of my "homepage" HAML file is:  `= content_for(:title, "Welcome to my home page!")`

Comment: That was the missing peace! Thanks a lot. I'm new in using HAML (but like it!) and I'm missing some basics.
If you'd write an answer, you get the credit :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32035/discussion-between-cdub-and-karsten-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your layout template, do:

`%title= content_for?(:title) ? "#{yield(:title)}" : "Default Title"`

Then in your content templates, do:

`= content_for(:title, "Welcome to my home page!")`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, still new line at the end. I've fixed it by chopping last character of title -  "#{yield(:title).chop}"